# how to find the type of unbalanced AVL tree?

Tags: java, avl-tree

I have write AVL-tree code but how can i write a code to find if my tree is unbalanced and it finds the unbalanced type Left of left, Right of left , Left of right and right of right  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a normal `DFS traversal` and at each node find the `max height of the left subtree` and `max height of the right subtree`.

Then the tree is balanced if `abs(height_left - height_right) <= 1` for all nodes.

To find the type of unbalanced tree (by which i think you mean the type of rotation that is requires to fix the tree), you can use left and right child pointers to deduce the type of rotation is required.